# Маршрутизация .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, маршрутизация

есть ссылка:

`https://test.com/company.php?name=name&id=1`

Нужно, что бы было вот так:

`https://test.com/company/company.php?name=name&id=1`

сделать нужно именно с помощью файла .htaccess, но что бы это никак не повлияло на другие страницы, как правильно это можно  сделать?

Answer (score 0):

так и сделать

```
RewriteRule ^company/company.php$  company.php  [QSA,L]
```

Comment: К сожалению, ничего не изменилось

Comment: @Apelsin2020 попробуйте `$` убрать. зы: вам что надо то, чтобы набирая в браузере вторую ссылку срабатывал первый скрипт? или как?

Comment: Нужно, что бы переходя на первую ссылку, в браузере отображалась вторая, но при этом нет ни каталога /company/ ни файла в нём